# How to get label value using python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm  a beginner to python programming. I want to print what text written in label when I click add button I tried I got the error was displayed

> totall = tot.cget("text") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no
> attribute 'cget'

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
root.title("Inventory System using Python")
root.geometry("1000x500")


def show():
    totall = tot.cget("text")
    print(totall)


tot = Label(root, text="sss",font="arial 22 bold").place(x=650, y=10)
Button(root, text="Add",command = show,height=3, width= 13).place(x=650, y=50)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you call `place` inline you define `tot` as `Label` that method returns None, so you can not get the text from a NoneType.

Split `place` method on another line and it will work.

```py
tot = Label(root, text="sss",font="arial 22 bold")
tot.place(x=650, y=10)
```